# Redirect loop on Google Site after setting access permissions

Tags: google-classic-sites, permissions

I have a website built with Google Sites and set the permissions so that only specific people can have access. Every time users visits the site, they will need to sign their respective Gmail accounts. Every time I try to sign in, I am flashed an error message saying that the "webpage has a redirect loop."

I've tried clearing caches and cookies this but still fails. I have also tried opening the site in the Incognito session (private browsing mode) but without luck.

I suspect that the problem is coming from the way that I have setup the page-level permissions for the site.

Here is the sitemap with page-level permissions in the site level.

[image: site level permissions]
The page-level permissions in the image below is a level lower than the site level.

[image: site level permissions for home]